# In Excel 2016 (Mac), how can I display a value with different formatting and color depending on whether a condition is true or false?

Tags: microsoft-excel, colors

I'm having problems with *IF* function in Microsoft Excel 2016 for Mac.

Basically what I want to do is to create an *IF* function in which the logical test would decide whether result of subtraction of two cells is above zero `((B1-A1)>0)`.

If the condition is *TRUE* then I want to show value of B1-A1 with plus sign `(+ (B1-A1))` and coloured in **green**.

If the condition is *FALSE* then I want to show value of B1-A1 with minus sign `(- (B1-A1))` and coloured in **red**.

Is this somehow possible?

Comment: Thank you for advice man. I don't specifically understand what is going on in this function you advised but if I just copy/paste it to Excel I get "The formula you typed contains an error".

Answer (score 1):

Define values in cell A1 and B1
Paste following formula where you need to see result

**=IF(B1-A1>0,B1-A1,B1-A1)**

After that follow below steps:

1. Go to conditional formating -> Highlight Cell Rules -> **Greater than**
2. Enter value 0 and select your desired color.
3. Go to conditional formating -> Highlight Cell Rules -> **Less than**
4. Enter value 0 and select your desired color.

[image]

**Note:** If you exactly need the values like (+ (B1-A1)), then follow Máté Juhász comment. However, my formula also shows positive and negative number but in different format. Give a try and let us know!

Comment: Thank you for advice. I tried doing it this way but I keep getting #VALUE! error.

Answer (score 0):

There's an alternative to an *IF* formula and conditional formatting that does both with a single format, provided that the true/false decision isn't complex. For positive and negative values, a [custom number format](https://support.office.com/client/Create-or-delete-a-custom-number-format-78f2a361-936b-4c03-8772-09fab54be7f4) for a cell will display a value with formatting that includes text and font colors. A cell formatted this way will look like this:

[image: example of formatted cells]

Select the Custom category of `Format Cells...` to define this custom number format: `[Green](_((+0));[Red](_((-0));0`. The number format has three sections separated by semicolons. The sections define the format for positive numbers, negative numbers, zero values.

[image: Format Cells dialog]

The sections can also specify number formats that will be displayed only if a number meets a condition by enclosing the condition in square brackets. The condition is a comparison operator and a value. For example, the following format displays numbers that are less than or equal to 5 in a red font and numbers that are greater than 10 in a green font. Additional formats, such as fill color and borders, can be applied with conditional formatting.

`[Red][<=5];[Green][>10]`

Here's the [complete explanation of custom number formats](https://support.office.com/client/Create-or-delete-a-custom-number-format-78f2a361-936b-4c03-8772-09fab54be7f4) from `Excel Help` on the menu bar.